# Error in shiny. package that is not in CRAN

Tags: r, shiny, deployment

I received an issue when I deploy my shinny app to https://www.shinyapps.io/. I know the problem; I am using a package that is not in CRAN. Name of the package is `gptchatteR`. It can be installed `install_github("isinaltinkaya/gptchatteR").` I can't colve it, need help.  Here is part of my code. Thanks

```
library(cutpointr)
library(pROC)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(devtools)
library(gptchatteR)
library(xml2)
# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App titleft
  titlePanel(" "),
  
  # Sidebar panel
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
...
`
```

Comment: Related to [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/my-shiny-app-wont-deploy-because-a-required-package-shiny-semantic-was-removed-from-cran-yesterday-what-do-i-do/119761/8)

Comment: relevant docs: https://docs.posit.co/shinyapps.io/getting-started.html#using-your-r-packages-in-the-cloud